# Align around symbol with qquad

Tags: math-mode, align

following Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,
              a4paper,
              DIV=calc
            ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

% Zustandsgrößen
\newcommand{\uC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{C_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\iL}{\mathrm{i_L}}
% Eingangsgrößen
\newcommand{\Uin}{\mathrm{U_{in}}}
\newcommand{\UD}[1]{\mathrm{U_{D_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Usboost}{\mathrm{U_{S_{boost}}}}
\newcommand{\UAC}{\mathrm{U_{AC}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
   \langle\iL\rangle = \overline{\iL}+\Delta\iL \qquad \langle\uC{1}\rangle &= \overline{\uC{1}}+\Delta\uC{1} \qquad \langle\uC{2}\rangle = \overline{\uC{2}}+\Delta\uC{2}\\
   \delta = \overline{\delta} + \Delta\delta \qquad \Uin &= \overline{\Uin} + \Delta\Uin \qquad \UAC = \overline{\UAC} + \Delta\UAC   
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

produces following Output:

[image: align-now]

i would like to align every Formula around (=) just like that:

```
iL = x + y        uc1 = x + y       uc2 = x + y
d  = x + y        Uin = x + y       UAC = x + y
```

but aligning with &,&&,&&& won't work.

Comment: Use `alignat*` instead.

Answer (score 6):

If `&&&`'s does not work, then what am I doing wrong here?

```
\documentclass[11pt,
              a4paper,
              DIV=calc
            ]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,markcase=ignoreuppercase,headsepline,plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

% Zustandsgrößen
\newcommand{\uC}[1]{\mathrm{u_{C_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\iL}{\mathrm{i_L}}
% Eingangsgrößen
\newcommand{\Uin}{\mathrm{U_{in}}}
\newcommand{\UD}[1]{\mathrm{U_{D_{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\Usboost}{\mathrm{U_{S_{boost}}}}
\newcommand{\UAC}{\mathrm{U_{AC}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \langle\iL\rangle &= \overline{\iL}+\Delta\iL \
  &
  \langle\uC{1}\rangle &= \overline{\uC{1}}+\Delta\uC{1}
  &
  \langle\uC{2}\rangle &= \overline{\uC{2}}+\Delta\uC{2}
  \\
  \delta &= \overline{\delta} + \Delta\delta
  &
  \Uin &=
  \overline{\Uin} + \Delta\Uin
  &
  \UAC &= \overline{\UAC} + \Delta\UAC
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You need one `&` per alignment, and one `&` to separate each alignment column. In this case 2x3-1 = 5 `&`'s

Comment: @adaptive in an ideal world we'd have one symbol for the alignment marker and a different for the "separate alignments" marker.